# When is the right time to draw?

Tags: c++, graphics

I just finished essential part of my own personal 2D engine in C++ and I'm kinda deciding how to complete the part where it is actually supposed to display everything on the screen, namely when do I call that function which does the job.

I don't have much idea of how does the graphic card work, my biggest experience is calling bios graphic services to write some stuff on the screen. Could you give me a hint on this please? Or maybe some keywords I should try to google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look up render loop.

In a game, you will do it in a loop. You can also look up game loop which is a related concept if you're working on a game.

Answer (score 1):

Are you rendering to a back buffer and then trying to display that?  Common terminology includes "flip" (as in page flipping) or "present".  If your copying from a back buffer to the screen, it might also be a "blit" (or blt) from "bit-block transfer".